# Java scanner and if-else statements

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How would I take a simple if-else statement using a Scanner for keyboard input, compare an integer against an argument and re prompt the user to input the integer again if it is not the desired result? Here is what I have, I think this should be fairly easy but I'm only learning;

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myInt = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

    int choice = myInt.nextInt();

    if (choice <= 10) {
        System.out.println("acceptable");
    } else {

                System.out.println("unacceptable");
                System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

            }
        }
    }
```

Any tips on how I should approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a loop. Also, don't forget that `choice` must be `>= 1` as well. Currently you would accept `0` (or any negative value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a while loop to keep asking for numbers and checking if they are acceptable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean acceptable=false;
    while(!acceptable){
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

        int choice = myInt.nextInt();

        if (choice <= 10 && choice>=1) {
            System.out.println("acceptable");
            acceptable=true;
        } else {

            System.out.println("unacceptable");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not your logic though.  *between 1 and 10* != `choice <= 10`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Fixed

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while (true) {
        if (insertNumber()) {
            break;
        }
    }

}

public static boolean insertNumber() {

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

    Scanner myInt = new Scanner(System.in);

    int choice = myInt.nextInt();

    if (choice <= 10) {
        System.out.println("acceptable");
        return true;

    } else {
        System.out.println("unacceptable");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, for the same reason OP's code snippet is wrong, logically. Please be mindful before posting answers.